# Queue and loops small issue

Tags: java, loops, queue

I had some question in my test. Now after discussing it with friends, answers were different and we were nowhere close to making a decision for our answers. Could any of you programmers solve it and share the answers? Thank you people!

This is the question:

Show what is written by the following segments of code, given that element1, element2 and element3 are int variables, and queue is an object that fits the abstract description of a queue as given in section 5.2, assume that you can store and retrieve values of type int and in queue.

a)

```
element1 = 1;
element2 = 0;
element3 = 4;
qeueu.enqueue(element2);
qeueu.enqueue(element1);
qeueu.enqueue(element1+element2);
element2 = queue.dequeu();
queue.enqueue(element3*element3);
queue.enqueue(element2);
queue.enqueue(3);
element1 = queue.dequeue();
system.out.println(element1 + " " + element2 + " " + element3);
while(!qeueu.isEmpty())
{
element1 = queue.dequeue();
system.out.println(element1);
}
```

b)

```
element1 = 4;
element2 = 0;
element3 = element1 + 1;
qeueu.enqueue(element2);
qeueu.enqueue(element2 + 1);
qeueu.enqueue(element1);
element2 = queue.dequeu();
element1 = element2 + 1;
queue.enqueue(element1);
queue.enqueue(element3);
while(!qeueu.isEmpty())
{
element1 = queue.dequeue();
system.out.println(element1);
}
system.out.println(element1 + " " + element2 + " " + element3);
```

Comment: What do you think the answer is? Why don't you execute the code and see what it does to confirm or infirm your answer?

Comment: Thats the idea, it's something solved by thinking, we were not allowed to test codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queue is `FIFO`:First In First Out.

Imagine that the queue looks something like this:

```
------------------------------------
------>                               
____________________________________
 ^                                 ^
 |                                 |
enquee                          dequeue
```

So when doing:

```
qeueu.enqueue(element2);
qeueu.enqueue(element1);
qeueu.enqueue(element1+element2);
```

The queue will look like this:

```
------------------------------------
---->  1    1    0  ---->                              
____________________________________
```

When you do:

```
element2 = queue.dequeu();
```

Then `element2` holds 0 now, and 0 is removed from the queue.

Now you do:

```
queue.enqueue(element3*element3);
queue.enqueue(element2);
queue.enqueue(3);
```

This will insert 4*4 which is 16 to the queue:

```
  ------------------------------------
   ---->  3   0   16   1    1   ---->          0 (0 was removed)                          
  ____________________________________
```

Now you have:

```
element1 = queue.dequeue();
```

`element1` will be 1, and 1 will be removed from the queue.

From here it's easy for you to complete the code, and part (b).

I highly recommend you to write the code and run it. (You can use a debugger to better understand what's happening)

Comment: So maroun for a, answer would be: 1 0 4 correct and 1? Thanks for your time! If you could also solve B so then i could try and get the answer correct?

Comment: Exactly. (Don't forget that you have a while loop right after the first print)

Comment: Ok, so it will print 1 0 4 before the loop and after the loop 1? Am i still right?

Comment: Inside the loop it prints the elements in the queue until the queue is empty.

Comment: ohhhhh yes! So inside the loop it will print all because element1 will be always set to the dequeu value meaning it will print everything inside the queue correct?

Comment: Thank you maroun! You helped me understand it a lot! Is it right if i wrote in my test that it will print all values in the queue or must i have listed the values?

Comment: I really don't know, depends on the lecturer :) The most important thing is that you understand how it works. Good Luck! :)

Comment: Thank you! i wrote that day 3   0   16   1 after the system printing. Is that a right answer? since 0 and 1 were removed.

Comment: It should be the opposite, look at the queue I've draw, it should be 1 16 0 3

Comment: ohhh yes! for b, wouldnt it be 5 4 5 for outside the loop and inside the loop : 5 5 1 0 ? i just did it